# null pointer exception for android button junit

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I'm writing unit tests for a simple android application. I have been able to get my other tests to run on their own. The problem arises when I try to string tests together. I get random null pointer exception errors, and I have no idea why. One might be on a button, another time it's on an EditText, and other times its a spinner. My code is listed below.

```
/*
 * This is a class to test various properties of temperature conversions. There are 
 * 3 widely used temperature scales, Fahrenheit, Celsius, and Kelvin. This class
 * will test the various properties of the conversions from one temperature to another.
 * 
 * The properties this class will test are as follows:
 * 1. No zero temperature of any one temperature will convert to a zero temperature
 *    in another scale.
 * 2. No temperature in the Celsius scale will convert to an equal temperature in 
 *    the Kelvin scale.
 * 3. For all temperatures above 574.6 degrees Fahrenheit, all temperatures in the
 *    Fahrenheit scale will be greater than the converted values in the Kelvin and
 *    Celsius scales.
 * 4. For all Fahrenheit temperatures below -40 degrees Fahrenheit, the Fahrenheit
 *    temperatures will be less than their converted values in the Kelvin and 
 *    Celsius scales.
 * 5. For all temperatures in the range of {-40, ..., 574.6} degrees Fahrenheit, all
 *    temperatures in Fahrenheit will be less than or equal to the converted 
 *    values in the Kelvin scale and less than or equal to the converted value in 
 *    the Celsius scale.
 *    
 */

package com.example.unitconversion1.test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.unitconversion1.UnitConversion;
import com.example.unitconversion1.R;
import com.example.unitconversion1.helper.ListGenerator;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class PropertyBasedTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<UnitConversion> {

    private EditText from, to;
    private Spinner spinnerFrom, spinnerTo;
    private Button convertButton;
    private UnitConversion unitConversion;
    public static final int CELSIUS = 0, FARENHEIT = 1, KELVIN = 2, NUMTESTS = 10;

    public PropertyBasedTest() {
        super("com.example.unitconversion1.test", UnitConversion.class);
    }

    public PropertyBasedTest(Class<UnitConversion> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        unitConversion = getActivity();
        from = (EditText) unitConversion.findViewById(R.id.value01);
        to = (EditText) unitConversion.findViewById(R.id.value02);
        spinnerFrom = (Spinner) unitConversion.findViewById(R.id.unit01);
        spinnerTo = (Spinner) unitConversion.findViewById(R.id.unit02);
        convertButton = (Button)unitConversion.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

    /*
     * This test checks to make sure that no zero temperature in any given scale
     * will convert to a zero value in another scale.
     */

    public void testNonZeroConversion() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                from.setText("0");
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                spinnerFrom.setSelection(KELVIN);
                convertButton.performClick();
                assertTrue(Double.parseDouble(to.getText().toString()) != 0);
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                spinnerFrom.setSelection(CELSIUS);
                convertButton.performClick();
                assertTrue(Double.parseDouble(to.getText().toString()) != 0);
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                spinnerFrom.setSelection(FARENHEIT);
                convertButton.performClick();
                assertTrue(Double.parseDouble(to.getText().toString()) != 0);
            }

        });
    }

    /*
     * This test will check that no temperature in the Kelvin scale will convert
     * to an equal value in the Celsius scale. The helper class ListGenerator
     * will be used to generate random values in Kelvin. Then the test will convert
     * the values to Celsius and compare the two.
     */

    public void testNotEqualTemperatures() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                ArrayList<BigDecimal> testNotEqualTemps = ListGenerator.getReals(NUMTESTS);
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                spinnerFrom.setSelection(KELVIN);
                spinnerTo.requestFocus();
                spinnerTo.setSelection(CELSIUS);
                for(BigDecimal rand: testNotEqualTemps){
                    from.setText(String.valueOf(rand.doubleValue()));
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    assertTrue(!from.getText().toString().equals(to.getText().toString()));
                }
            }

        });
    }

    /*
     * This test checks that any temp in Fahrenheit above 574.6 will always yield a result
     * in Kelvin and Celsius values that are less than the given Fahrenheit value.
     */

    public void testFahrenheitGreater() {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ArrayList<BigDecimal> testGreaterTemps = ListGenerator.getRealsGreaterThan(NUMTESTS,574.6);
                BigDecimal fromVal;
                BigDecimal toVal;
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                spinnerFrom.setSelection(FARENHEIT);
                assertNotNull("Check to see button is not null",convertButton);
                for(BigDecimal rand: testGreaterTemps){
                    assertNotNull("Check to see rand value is not null.", rand);
                    from.setText(String.valueOf(rand.doubleValue()));
                    spinnerTo.setSelection(CELSIUS);
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    fromVal = new BigDecimal(from.getText().toString());
                    toVal = new BigDecimal(to.getText().toString());
                    assertTrue("Fahrenheit is always bigger", fromVal.compareTo(toVal) > 0);
                    spinnerTo.setSelection(KELVIN);
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    toVal = new BigDecimal(to.getText().toString());
                    assertTrue("Fahrenheit is always bigger", fromVal.compareTo(toVal) > 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * This test checks that any temp in Fahrenheit below -40 will always yield a result
     * in Kelvin and Celsius values that are greater than the given Fahrenheit value.
     */

    public void testFahrenheitLessThan() {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ArrayList<BigDecimal> testLesserTemps = ListGenerator.getRealsGreaterThan(NUMTESTS,-40.0d);
                BigDecimal fromVal;
                BigDecimal toVal;
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                spinnerFrom.setSelection(FARENHEIT);
                for(BigDecimal rand: testLesserTemps){
                    from.setText(String.valueOf(rand.doubleValue()));
                    spinnerTo.setSelection(CELSIUS);
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    fromVal = new BigDecimal(from.getText().toString());
                    toVal = new BigDecimal(to.getText().toString());
                    assertTrue("Fahrenheit is always bigger", fromVal.compareTo(toVal) < 0);
                    spinnerTo.setSelection(KELVIN);
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    toVal = new BigDecimal(to.getText().toString());
                    assertTrue("Fahrenheit is always bigger", fromVal.compareTo(toVal) < 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * This test will check values of Fahrenheit between -40 and 574.6. For all temps
     * in this range, the value should be larger than it's converted value in Celsius, 
     * and it should be less than th converted value in Kelvin.
     */

    public void testFahrenheitInBetween() throws InterruptedException {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ArrayList<BigDecimal> testInBetweenTemps = null;
                try {
                    testInBetweenTemps = ListGenerator.getRealsInBetween(NUMTESTS, 574.6d, -40d);
                    Log.i(getName(), "ArrayList has been created for In between");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(getName(), "Something went wrong creating the ArrayList for Inbetween");
                }
                BigDecimal fromVal;
                BigDecimal toVal;
                spinnerFrom.requestFocus();
                **spinnerFrom.setSelection(FARENHEIT)**;
                for(BigDecimal rand: testInBetweenTemps){
                    from.setText(String.valueOf(rand.doubleValue()));
                    spinnerTo.setSelection(CELSIUS);
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    fromVal = new BigDecimal(from.getText().toString());
                    toVal = new BigDecimal(to.getText().toString());
                    assertTrue("Fahrenheit is bigger than Celsius", fromVal.compareTo(toVal) > 0);
                    spinnerTo.setSelection(KELVIN);
                    convertButton.performClick();
                    toVal = new BigDecimal(to.getText().toString());
                    assertTrue("Fahrenheit is less than Kelvin", fromVal.compareTo(toVal) < 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the activity I'm testing.

```
package com.example.unitconversion1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class UnitConversion extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    double v1, v2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.tempUnits, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        Spinner spinner01 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unit01);
        Spinner spinner02 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unit02);

        spinner01.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner01.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner02.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner02.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    public void convertTemperature(View view) {
        /*
         * First we setup the views and then check to make sure we
         * don't have a null value.
         */
        int from = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.unit01)).getSelectedItemPosition(), 
                to = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.unit02)).getSelectedItemPosition();
        EditText fromValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value01);
        if(fromValue.getText().length()==0) return;

        /*
         * Now we populate the class level variables with the values to convert.
         */
        v1 = Double.parseDouble(fromValue.getText().toString());
        v2 = (TempConverter.convert(v1, from, to));

        /*
         * Now we display the converted value in the second EditText view.00
         */
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.value02)).setText(Double.toString(v2));

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Finally, here are the filtered messages from logcat.

```
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at com.example.unitconversion1.test.PropertyBasedTest$2.run(PropertyBasedTest.java:203)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-01 05:21:50.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2018):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried testing in different orders only to see the previous test that was failing pass, and then see the null pointer exception pop up inn another test. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Should I try to make one thread sleep? Or should I try to combine the tests to see if they can work in the same thread? That kind of defeats the purpose of test independence, but at this point I just want to make some progress. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

**Update**
I highlighted the line in the code block quote, but doesn't seem to render as bold. The line in question is below:
`spinnerFrom.setSelection(FARENHEIT);`
This line in particular is in the test case "testFahrenheitInBetween".

Comment: can you please highlight line no : 203 code at PropertyBasedTest class ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using break-points or printing to the console at different stages of the creation process to see where something is being created and where its not. If everything appears to be created just fine, and then you still get the nullPointerException, I would suspect something is wrong with the way you are passing references to the objects. Maybe something is not getting returned the way you want.

Another thought: with Unit tests I've always understood that comparing results to literal values is best. In other words, feed your methods a set value and compare the results to a set value of what you know it should be, instead of something vague like > 0 and such.

Good luck.